# No elements returned from array

Tags: php, arrays, count, element

I asked a question about same code but got lost in translation

Here's what the question comes down to. I validate if a certrain var is a an array, then I want an element out of it but returns no value. What's going on?

EDIT: I'm adding the code that explains where the string is coming from. It's a guestbook where I need to come up with a solution that is NOT a database of session variable. It's what my course requires;

```
   $file="gb_berichten.txt";            
$datum = date("d-m-Y");

$bericht = "<p><b>naam: </b>$_POST[naam] <br>
            <b>email: </b>$_POST[email] <br>
            <b>onderwerp: </b>$_POST[subj]<br><br>
            <b>bericht: </b>$_POST[bericht]<br>
            <b>verzonden op: </b> $datum
            </p>
            <hr/>
            ";

        if (is_writable ($file)){
            $fp= fopen($file, "a")
                or die ("kan de file niet openen<br>");
                fwrite ($fp, $bericht);
                fclose($fp);
            }//end if writable

        else {
            print ("bestand $file is niet beschikbaar voor schrijven<br>");
            }   

        if (is_readable($file)){
            $fp = fopen($file, "r");
            //$tekst = fread($fp, filesize($file));
            $inhoud = file_get_contents($file);
            $berichten =  implode(' ', array_reverse(explode("<hr/>", $inhoud)));
            fclose ($fp); 
            print($berichten);
            }

        else {
            print("niet mogelijk om bestand te lezen");
            } 




    //check of $berichten een string is
    if (is_string($berichten)){
       print ("string ok"); 
    } else{
       print ("string niet ok");} 
       // returns string ok 

       //convert back to array  
       $berichtenArr =  explode("<hr/>", $berichten);
       if (is_array($berichtenArr )) {
          print("<p style='color:red'>Array OK<p>");
       } else {
          print("<p style='color:red'>Array not OK<p>");
       }
       //returns Array OK

       $secondElem = $berichtenArr[1];
       print("<p style='color:red'>second element is: $secondElem<p>"); // returns no value

       $aantalBer = count($berichtenArr);
       print("<p style='color:red'>amount of messages   is: $aantalBer<p>"); //returns 1
    }
```

Comment: what's the original value of your string?

Comment: There seems to be a `}` too much. Where does the first `if` statement end exactly?

Comment: like Dogbert said: the original value of your string is important here. If this is not provided, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: You need to work on your indentation. It's making your code very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done `explode("<hr/>")`, but in one of your comments elsewhere, you state that your string has `multiple <hr /> elements`.

Can you spot the problem there?

I'll give you a clue: `<hr/>` is not the same as `<hr />`.

You probably need to modify your `explode()` to take both into account.

It's also possible that you might have `<hr>` as another valid possibility. (In fact, there's a lot more possiblities than that, since is is valid for the `<hr>` tag to contain `id`, `class` and `style` attributes, all of which will be missed by a simple `explode()`.

If you want to pick up all valid possibilities, you may want to use something like `preg_split()` instead. (note although I suggest that, I should add that it is generally considered bad form to use a regex to do pattern-matching in HTML. But since you're just looking for the simple `<hr>` tag, it should be possible to do a good enough job with `preg_match()` without having to make your matching pattern too complex).

Comment: as you can see now the <hr/> is exactly the same in the string generated as it is in the argument of the explode function. so me mentioning the space in hr is in my questions but no my code

Comment: @Jack: Okay. I see in your edited code that you only have `<hr/>`. I stand by my comment that it would be better to be able to cope with different variations. However, given the example you've provided, the only `<hr/>` in the string is at the end of the string, which would result in only one element being generated in the `explode()`, which answers the question as to why you're not seeing anything in the second element.

Comment: Yes that would make perfect sense. Thing is the stringcontent comes from an html form that are guestbook messages. Of course I made sure I stored some messages (and therefore a couple of <hr/> elements) in the file before I started looking for a multiple elements in my array. My guestbook page actually outputs the messages the way I want to in case you're thinking something could be wrong with my file writing.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one element in your array.  That's why you get no value when you try to get the second element.

Add

```
print_r($berichtenArr);
```

and all will be clear.

Comment: How do you know that there's only one element? If the string $berichten has multiple <hr /> elements?(which is the case)

Comment: @Jack_Anyway print("<p style='color:red'>amount of messages  is: $aantalBer<p>"); //returns 1...

Comment: `$aantalBer = count($berichtenArr);` --> returns 1.  That means you have 1 element.

Comment: @Jack did you write the code yourself? `count($berichtenArr)` returns 1. It seems pretty obvious to conclude there is one entry based on your code example.

Comment: P.S.: Notice that "<hr/>" and "<hr />" are different.

Comment: well yes I wrote the code myself and yes of course in this example obviously the the countfunction actually does return 1. But to repose my question I wonder why it is only returning 1 if I know my string consists of multimple <hr/> elements that separates them.

Comment: @Jack, that is a question that we can only answer by seeing what your original string looks like :)

Comment: If you `print_r($berichtenArr);`, then you'll see why it is only returning 1.

Comment: @awm using `print_r` on the array does not clear up why there is one entry in the array even though the originally exploded string contains multiple `<hr/>`'s. This probably is caused by the fact that multiple variants of `<hr/>` syntax are used in the string, but this can still only be answered fully by seeing the original string.

Comment: @Aron You're absolutely right, of course.  The **only** code we should even be looking at here is `print_r($berichten); $berichtenArr =  explode("<hr/>", $berichten); print_r($berichenArr);`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code your array contains only 1 element so and which is on index 0 .

when you are printing the array value you are referring to index 1.

```
$secondElem = $berichtenArr[0];
```

and also check the array structure by printing it `print_r($berichtenArr)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with your logic: the function `explode()` takes a string as input and in the previous lines you have made sure that it is **not** a string, so that code will not work.

**Edit:** Sorry, I missed the first closing `}` (there seems to be one too much...) but you still need to wrap your first `if` statement around all the rest of your code as you cannot continue with your `explode` if the result of the first `if` tells you it´s not a string.

Comment: that's not true - the previous lines checked it, but it will do the array code either way. (the indentation is misleading; note the `}` after `"string niet ok"`)

Comment: @Spudley You are right, I had already edited my answer but there seems to be a `}` too much anyway so I added a comment below the OP's question.

Comment: How do you mean? I though I actually checked if $berichten would be a string with that if statement whick returns that $berichten IS a string so why wouldnt  $berichten be a string?

Comment: @Jack_Anyway I haven´t seen the output of the code, just the code itself, but either way you should not continue with your code if the first `if` returns `string niet ok` so you should put the rest of the code inside the first `if` statement.